# multiple with statement in one line for python

Tags: python, with-statement

Can I write multiple `with` statement in one line in python? For

```
with suppress(Exception): del a;
with suppress(Exception): del b;
```

is there something like?

```
with suppress(Exception): del a;|| with suppress(Exception): del b;
```

Comment: I don't understand the usecase

Comment: Have you tried `with suppress(Exception): del a; del b`?

Comment: @MarkRansom that's not quite the same: that way, `del b` isn't executed if `del a` throws, whereas in OP's first code snippet, `del b` is always executed.

Comment: @slothrop good point.  Then maybe the suggested line without the `||` would work?

Comment: Python only allows *simple* statements (roughly speaking, ones that don't use `:` to introduce an arbitrarily complex body) to be joined on a single line, using `;`. There is no way to combine two `with` statements on a single line.

Comment: @MarkRansom indeed, I don't know of a better way than "just accept the line break".

Comment: (I suspect it is debatable whether `;`-joining would be accepted as a proposal today if it weren't already in the language.)

Comment: @chepner I wouldn't predict a debate at all, it would be similar to what happens with `from __future__ import braces`.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not practical or supported and will make your code worse and harder to understand and maintain

If you manage to accomplish doing so (which is a feature of Python!), it won't be Pythonic

To quote from the [Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/)

> Sparse is better than dense.
> Readability counts.

That said, you may really have have a technical reason to do this (for example, I've wanted to write very terse code when doing evils in a [pdb REPL](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)) - in such a case, try to package the full logic you really want to do and *transform it* into what you need

- make a new function and call it
- make a new context manager with all the desired functionality
- make a library and import it
- "just don't do that" (if something seems really awkward, there may be a better way!)
- `exec` a magic string (see also: this is evil)